# C++/CLI in .net compact framework

Tags: .net, c++-cli, compact-framework

Is C++/CLI available in .net compact framework ? When I google it says it is not available but the articles are very old. So is it available now ?

Comment: If we reply in the negative now, will you ask the same question again in a few years?

Comment: Isn't this a "try and see" question? Make a C++/CLI app, if you can successfully run it on a test device, obviously this works.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't build C++/CLI apps for the .NET CF.

The last version of VS which can build for the CF is VS2008, so everything you'll find to do with .NET CF is old.

You also need to be aware that the marshalling code is much less fully-featured than in the full framework, but sadly the limitations only show-up at run time (various not-supported exceptions).  So even P/Invoke and its surroundings may cause you pain.

Personally, I wouldn't start a .NET CF project today, though I do support some existing ones.

Comment: We are using VS2008. Can we build C++/CLI app in VS2008? Thanks

Comment: No, you can't.  And you can't in any later version of VS either, because there are no later versions which support the CF at all, in any way.